# How do you make a loop cut a straight line (not follow the contours of the mesh)?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was watching a tutorial video [(Which you can find here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaPd4ieTmng) and at the 18:00 mark he creates a loop cut, then appears to press 'S' (scale) and mashes a few other keys that aren't displayed and the loop cut suddenly becomes completely horizontal and no longer follows the contours of the mesh.

What is happening here and how can I accomplish this, or something similar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He presses <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, which scales the selected vertices to `0` on the Z axis, flattening them.

Another useful shortcut is <kbd>E</kbd> during edge slide, which aligns the new loop to one of the adjacent loops (press <kbd>F</kbd> to switch between loops).

[image]

Comment: AAH of course. This is just what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [knife tool](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide).

For a plane along the X Y axis, go to top view <kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>. Press <kbd>K</kbd> that starts the knife tool. To constrain the new edge to a straight ling press <kbd>C</kbd>. Then <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> click on the top edge, move the mouse down and <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> click on the last edge.
[image: knife tool]