# How to make an edge loop that is parallel to one of the sides of the face loop?

Tags: modeling, edges

How to make an edge loop that is parallel to one of the sides of the face loop?

Not this - [image]

But this - [image]

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14481/599

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need a new loop cut:
In edit mode, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> to add a new  loop cut. Then during edge slide press <kbd>E</kbd> which aligns the new loop to one of the adjacent face loops. <kbd>F</kbd> switches between face loops.

If a new edge loop is not needed:
Then select a edge loop <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> > *Edge Slide* to start the edge sliding, then during edge slide press <kbd>E</kbd> which aligns the new loop to one of the adjacent face loops. <kbd>F</kbd> switches between face loops.

These are the options for edge slide as shown in the 3D view header.
[image: edge slide options]

Comment: Also note that you can use `GG` instead of `Ctrl E` > Edge slide.