# Lining up vertices/edges horizontally along a slanted object without altering the shape of the object?

Tags: vertices

I have a slanted object with verts aligned along the slanted edge, however I wish to have the verts aligned horizontally (in Global orientation) while still maintaining their alignment with the edge they are placed on.

[image]

If I <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, this gets them all perfectly in line, but then it changes the shape of object as it pulls all the verts in a bit.
If I set the edge as the transform orientation, and use snapping to align the verts, then it aligns them as they are currently are in the screenshot.

In essence, I need to mix the 2 methods to align in Global orientation while maintaining the edge alignment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/slanted-loop-cuts and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14481/how-do-you-make-a-loop-cut-a-straight-line-not-follow-the-contours-of-the-mesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option here IMO is to use a ***knife tool***. Press <kbd>K</kbd> and place the knife icon on the vertex to snap to it. Then press <kbd>C</kbd> to make a straight cut. Then select the angled edge and press <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Dissolve Edges*.
[image]

To align other edge loops to the newly created horizontal one add an edge loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, press <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>F</kbd>.
[image]