# Loop cut straight line

Tags: 3d-view

I am doing a table and need to make a cutout, but when I use the loop cut tool it doesn't make a straight line, but a curved one. How can I make a straight one?

[image: Table]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75915/lining-up-vertices-edges-horizontally-along-a-slanted-object-without-altering-th